# How to Run a script or get adb devices from machine 1 to mobile device which is connected machine 2?

Tags: adb

I am attempting to run a Script from Machine 1. [Script would be calabash or Appium]. In machine 1 i didnt connected any device and In machine 2 I have connected 2 Android devices.

> Machine 1 and Machine 2 are connected via LAN. so I can able to ping machine 2 from machine 1.

Now My question is 
**Is there any posibility to Access devices via adb which is conneced in Machine 2. So that i can able to run my Script ?**

I am using two windows machine.

Comment: This question appears to be more suitable for [su]. Anyhow, you can run an SSH server on Machine 2 and access it from Machine 1. Now, you would be in Machine 2 remotely and can do whatever you want. Perhaps, pstools can also help: http://www.howtogeek.com/school/sysinternals-pro/lesson8/all/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that using adb connect REMOTE_MACHINE_IP:XXXX .

where XXXX is the port of the remote machine.

Sources:

http://www.41post.com/5003/programming/android-adb-remote-emulator-access

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13278429/how-to-set-up-adb-for-remote-machine-development-and-local-device-deployment

Comment: Is that possible to Run Script from Machine 1. ?

Comment: @YusufM as per the stack overflow answer, it should work, but i havent tried running script.

Comment: adb connect requires the PC and device to be connected under hotspot/Wi-Fi/USB_tethering. None of the conditions are true here, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @Firelord so without adb I am not able to run calabash script on machine 2.. Am I correct ? So any other possibility to bring up that devices on machine 1 without using remote..? ?